# Castle Windsor - Registering multiple interfaces with same generic factory method

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor to register a number of interfaces each of which can created with a generic factory method. i.e.

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IFirstService))
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => GetService<IFirstService>())
    .LifeStyle.Singleton);

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ISecondService))
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => GetService<ISecondService>())
    .LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

Rather than add registration code for each interface, can I use the `Types` method to register them all in one go (all interfaces derive from `IService`) eg:

```
container.Register(Types
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .Where(t => typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .Configure(c => c.UsingFactoryMethod(k => GetService<?>()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because generic method calls a usually set up by the compiler you can't exactly do that at runtime without invoking using reflection, however with an `object GetService(Type t)` signature instead of a generic argument you can do this:

```
container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IService>()
    .Configure(c =>
        c.UsingFactoryMethod((k, ctx) => GetService(ctx.RequestedType))
    )
);
```

This is using the `UsingFactoryMethod` overload that provides the `CreationContext`.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed I would be looking at reflection. Luckily my `GetService` method is just a wrapper around an object based method, so your solution works for me. The key was finding the overload which would give me the required type. I love Castle Windsor, but sometime the documentation is a bit lacking!

Comment: The problem with documentation is that everyone uses things in different ways and Windsor has so many extensibility points. We are happy to review and merge in any contributions to our documentation on GitHub via a pull request.